# How to keep session alive for 1week without logout PHP, overwriting default server values?

Tags: php

How to keep session alive for 1week without logout PHP, overwriting default server values?

I need to do this in the PHP code.

Comment: Why do you need this?  Leaving sessions open this long is not a good idea (for example, session hijacking would be much easier if you have a week to find a valid session number instead of 20mins).  There may be a better solution to the original problem if you let us know what that is.

Comment: Since this is an internal system, and the users leave there browsers open for days and then complain that there session has expired and I'm fedup for that

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set the session lifetime in your script by using the session_set_cookie_params -function call before the session is started. The first argument of the function call defines the session lifetime in seconds relative to the server time (so make sure the server clock is correct):

For example, to make a session last a week:

```
session_set_cookie_params(3600 * 24 * 7);
session_start();
```

This will override the setting in the php.ini -file.

Make sure to check up on the function documentation on the PHP -site: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php

Comment: when browser closed then session will be expired in this case write?

Comment: I beleive this answer is not entirely reliable as there is a chance (depending on your settings in php.ini) that the garbage collector runs and destroys the session.

Comment: Yo should add too: ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 3600 * 24 * 7);

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to add this even though it's an old thread for the sake of completeness for future googlers:

> Beware if you are on a Debian system.

The `/etc/cron.d/php5` script will still clean your `/var/lib/php5/` directory containing your sessions based on the `php.ini` value `session.gc_maxlifetime`.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution:

You say people are leaving open their browsers for days and complain that session expire. Simple solution: don't let session expire by sending an keep-alive request using eg. XMLHttpRequest every 10 minutes.